# How to use parameterized query in Excel using column as parameter?

Tags: excel, parameterized-query, excel-external-data

I am trying to develop a spreadsheet that can locate corresponding records in an external data source.  So, let's say I have Column A with a list of identity values.  I want to develop Column B, which perhaps shows a count of rows in the table with that value.  Something like:

```
A              B
758348    "=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE IDVALUE=$A$1"
173483    "=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE IDVALUE=$A$2"
```

... and so on.  So, I thought I would use a parameterized query (where IDVALUE=?), but that prompts me to input the parameter value, not use the value from the cell to the left.  Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Query or Data Connections in Excel?

Answer (score 20):

> I would use a parameterized query (where IDVALUE=?), but that prompts
>   me to input the parameter value

From what you mentioned  I understand you are using MS Query and you need to follow the following steps

**Steps to make a parameterized query in Excel use a cell value as parameter**

1. First go to the Data tab in Excel and Select MS Query under External Data Sources

[image: MS Query]

2. A pop up appears asking you to choose data source. Select the data source or add a new data source and select it. Make sure to uncheck `Use the query wizard to create or edit queries` it is not very useful in most cases

[image: Data Source]

3. Then a pop up appears asking you to add table select any table for now. It is better to select a table with less rows.

[image: add table]

4. Then a Query window appears with the table you have selected and its data

[image: query window]

5. Then click on the `view` menu and uncheck `tables`. This removes the graphically representation in query window and makes it easier to alter you sql query

[image: View menu]

6. Click on the `SQL` button below the `format` menu in query window. A pop up comes where you can edit the query as you wish. Make sure to add question mark(s) for the parameter(s) you want.

[image: edit query]

7. Then a pop up appears ask you for parameter value(s) enter some valid value for now

[image: parameter]

8. Then the query window shows the result of query based on the parameter entered

[image: result]

9. Click on the `exit` button below the `view` menu in query window. Then the query window closes and Import Data pop up comes asking where in excel to display the result. Choose accordingly

[image: import]

10. Then click on Properties button on left before you click OK. A new pop up appears with the default usage tab selected.

[image: Properties]

11. Make any changes needed in this tab and click on `Definition` tab. Click on `Parameters` button in bottom of the pop up next to `edit query` button

[image: Definition]

12. `Parameters` pop up comes displaying the parameters used in the query. Here you must select the `Get the value from following cell` radio button to select the  value of cell as the parameter for the query. Click OK and you should be done.

    [image: parameter value]

---

This method is for people with no VBA experience. If you know VBA then refer to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/294890) to achieve the something similar using VBA.

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive an error that it is not possible to create parameters for a query that cannot be represented graphically.
I guess that as a workaround I should create a view in the DB, but is there other solution for those who has no appropriate permissions in the DB?

Comment: This still only gains an input parameter for the first row of the column.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this I would create a UDF and have the backend of that function connecting to your access database. Something like this:

```
Public Function countMyTable(IDValue As Double) As Long
'Requires:// Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
'Requires:// Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = Access.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(DBFilePath, False, False)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable WHERE IDValue = " & IDValue, dbOpenSnapshot)
rs.MoveLast
countMyTable = rs(0)
db.close
End Function
```

Hope this helps, TheSilkCode