# Excel Input Parameters query

Tags: sql, excel

This is a simple sql query.

```
SELECT cli.CLIENTE as clientet
FROM [V30].[dbo].[parmaq] as par,[V30].[dbo].[clientes] as cli 
where cli.CLIENTE=par.EMPRESA 
and par.data > 'parameter1' and par.data < 'parameter2'
```

What I would like to do is having an executable or something that allows me to enter the values from **'parameter1'** and **'parameter2'** to finally show the results with an excel. I am not sure if the excel itself can put input parameters on a query without catching the values from a column.

Comment: Short answer, yes.  And I believe you can search related information in google or here, i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413092/how-to-use-parameterized-query-in-excel-using-column-as-parameter

Comment: That's right.  Just use the question mark `?` as your parameter.  From there, Excel will ask you how you want to populate it, and you'll have a lot of options from there -- for example, have it pull the data from another Excel cell and even refresh automatically if the cell value changes