# pass excel cell values to SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, syntax

I read all the posts with similar questions but couldn't find a working solution.

What I try to do is take value from excel cell and put it in a SQL query (again in excel) so when the value is changed, the SQL query is also changed accordingly.

For example I have two sheets in a workbook and in Sheet 1 I have two dates in cells a2 and b2.
I want to pass them in a SQL query so the data extracted is constrained between these two dates.

The query I tried in different syntax variants is:

```
SELECT
   [INSTANCEDATE] 
FROM
   [hrsb].[dbo].[cVBAY] 
WHERE
   INSTANCEDATE >= [sheet1$a2]
AND INSTANCEDATE <= [sheet1$b2]
```

This does not work. I usually get an error that column b name is invalid. Seems that it doesn't make difference between excel values and DB parameters.

Of course, if instead of reference to excel cell values, I put just date range it works.

Could you please advise how this can be done?

Comment: I think we need some more information: You stated that you're doing the sql query in Excel. How? Is it through VBA coding? Power Query? Microsoft Query? The method being used can greatly affect an answer's usefulness.

Comment: I think here is the problem - I thought it is enough to add [sheet1$a2] in the query in order to pass the value from the cell. Actually I don't use none of the above.

What I do is to open the saved query from existing connections in  excel, make only connection (without doing the actual DB extract) and edit the connection by adding in properties - command text the above.

Probably this is my mistake. Please correct me.

Comment: From the description in your comment, I believe you are using Microsoft query. I would recommend taking a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26443279/9259306) as I was able to successfully add a parameter from an Excel cell to a simple query by following it's instuctions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try and get back to report the results.

Comment: Mistella, your answer works. The query is converted in another format / syntax by excel and works. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use parameterized query in Excel using column as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413092/how-to-use-parameterized-query-in-excel-using-column-as-parameter)