# How to return sql query results for multiple rows in excel where each row has parameters

Tags: excel, parameters, rows

I have an EXCEL spread sheet with 3000+ rows, i need to search a sql db to verify that a record exist for that row's data.

I have reviewed [How to use parameterized query in Excel using column as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413092/how-to-use-parameterized-query-in-excel-using-column-as-parameter). I can make it work for each row if I do a query for each row's parameter. but not for all 3000+. I also do not need the "column header" in the results.

I would like to have a query for each row for their parameters
such as i have three columns Location, CityCode, CountyCode
I want to return the MasterID which is Selecdt masterid where location = a1 and citycode = b1 and CountyCode = C1, for all 3000 rows.

Comment: Always helps to say what type of database you're working with.

Comment: Sorry I am working with SQL

Comment: SQL is a language used by many databases - do you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am working with MS SQL (2014)