# Use cell values from worksheet as part of SQL parameters

Tags: excel, oracle, excel-external-data

I used a parameterized query (where IDVALUE=?) to retrieve data from Oracle database with MS Excel. That works for me to input the parameter value (numeric). But for text/ string in cell A1 as ID, I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID ="'?'"
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID ='?'
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID =?
```

- Input 'ABC123' with/ without a single quote in cell A1
- Use formula =CHAR(39)&A1&CHAR(39)

None of them works.

***Read through this before, I still can't find success***
[How to use parameterized query in Excel using column as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413092/how-to-use-parameterized-query-in-excel-using-column-as-parameter)

Your ideas/ suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "None of them works." - what does that mean?

Comment: Can't retrieve the correct data from Oracle database