# Excel - set up parametrized data source

Tags: excel

I want to filter data from an external data source.

I have an Excel sheet coming from a MySQL data source ([IN]).

Now I want a new sheet [FILTERED] having data from the sheet [IN] filtered on some user parameteres defined in sheet [PARAM]:  {appointmentDay} and {idSite}

Ideally the sheet [FILTERED] should be updated automatically if the filters {appointmentDay} and {idSite} would change.

I suppose there should be a very easy solution, but unfortunately I don't find anything going into this direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
[How to use parameterized query in Excel using column as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413092/how-to-use-parameterized-query-in-excel-using-column-as-parameter)

In short: 
1) you create a data source using "Microsoft Query"
2) in the where you use ? as placeholder for parameters
3) in the connection properties you define where to look for the paramters